# Prevent org source block face from bleeding out in fold

Tags: org-mode

The problem is that when there is one line in between folded headings with source blocks the text properties of the *#end-src* line bleeds out. You can see the lines bleeding on the right in the image.

[image: Observe Lines Bleeding out on the right]

#### Update Progress So Far

#### step 1

To do this I have taken two steps.

The first is to unfontify the end of the last line of a subtree when hiding it if that line is the end of a source block. That's the line responsible for the bleeding. This will ensure that the font face doesn't bleed out when a block is hidden with `outline-hide-subtree`.

```
(defun dwim-unfontify-last-line-of-subtree (&rest _)
  "Unfontify last line of subtree if it's a source block."
  (save-excursion
    (org-end-of-subtree)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (when (looking-at-p (rx "#+end_src"))
      (font-lock-unfontify-region
       (line-end-position) (1+ (line-end-position))))))

(advice-add #'outline-hide-subtree :after #'dwim-unfontify-last-line-of-subtree)
```

#### step 2

The second step is the hard one. I determined that `outline-show-heading` is the fundamental function for showing headings. This function checks if the heading being shown has

```
(defun dwim-fontify-last-line-of-block (&rest _)
  "Do what I mean: fontify last line of source block.
When the heading has a source block as the last item (in the subtree) do one of the
  following:
If the source block is now visible, fontify the end its last line.
If it's invisible, unfontify its last line."
  (let (font-lock-fn invisible-p heading-name)
    (save-excursion
      ;; Debugging
      ;; (save-match-data
      ;;   (beginning-of-line)
      ;;   (looking-at
      ;;    (rx bol (+ "*") "\s" (submatch (+ (not (any "\n"))))))
      ;;   (setq heading-name (match-string-np 1)))
      (org-end-of-subtree)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (looking-at-p (rx "#+end_src"))
        (setq invisible-p (outline-invisible-p (line-end-position)))
        (setq font-lock-fn
              (if invisible-p
                  #'font-lock-unfontify-region
                #'font-lock-fontify-region))
        ;; Debugging
        ;; (message "-%s-’s end_src is %svisible"
        ;;          heading-name
        ;;          (if invisible-p "in" ""))
        (funcall font-lock-fn
                 (line-end-position)
                 (1+ (line-end-position)))))))

(advice-add #'outline-show-heading :after #'dwim-fontify-last-line-of-block)
```

#### problem

This is extremely close to working. If you use `outline-toggle-children` to display the children of a subtree and every child is a subtree (in other words each is displayed as a folded headline), the last source block of every headline should be invisible. That's because all the headings are folded. But `(outline-invisible-p (line-end-position))` says the last child of that subtree remains visible.

The picture below shows what I mean. You can see the last child of the Top level headings is bleeding out. And the last child of the level `Completion` heading is bleeding. This is what happens when I displayed them with `outline-toggle-fold`.

[image: last child]]

Comment: In general, messing with the `text-properties` (expressly setting the text properties) when `font-lock` is active is just asking for trouble.  The best practice, in my opinion, is to use one or the other.  Since flat-text files in `org-mode` use `font-lock` and `org-agenda-mode` uses `text-properties`, I would suggest any changes you make be limited as such.  The easiest solution is to not use a background face, except for an active `region` ...  There is a lengthy recent discussion on the Emacs Devel list spanning several days about face attributes that extend to the end of the line ...

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this. I'll investigate how to do the same thing with `font-lock`.

Comment: Here is a link to the opening thread I referred to above where the Emacs developers discuss face properties that extend to the end of the display line (e.g., end of the text area / window body width):  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2019-08/msg00132.html  In a couple of those posts, they compare/contrast terminal and GUI builds where certain face attributes extend to the end of the display line ....  Inasmuch as these things are handled internally by the display engine, Lisp workarounds may include stop highlighting before reaching EOL; or, fold to next line without face ...

Comment: Thanks for this link. I tried folding to the next line without face by setting the second argument of `outline-flag-region` to the start of the next line. However I like having a blank line in between fold. Also doing this results in `end_src` lines looking like this: `#+end_src...`. Right now, I'm thinking the best workaround my be, as you mentioned, "stop highlighting before reaching EOL". However I would want to do this conditionally: only just before I fold a heading. And to highlight normally just before unfolding.

Comment: Years ago, I stopped using the background face for everything (except `region`) because of problems like this ...  I also stopped using bold ... but I forget the reason at the moment for that decision.

Comment: Was it that bad? This is the only thing that really bothered me. This problem has been on my todo-lists for months (if not over a year). It may seem small to others but it annoys the hell out of me. I am almost at a working solution (see update). I just need to figure out why I am unable to accurately determine whether I'm at an invisible line in my advice to `outline-show-children`.

Comment: I have a mild / medium case of OCD and I have fallen in love with Emacs because I can change just about anything that irks me.  It has been several years since I started using Emacs and the only thing that comes to mind at the moment is the built-in `hl-line.el` library that defaults to highlighting the background, which caused me to switch to other face attributes; e.g., now I just use the underline attribute to highlight the current line in some buffers.  Your issue probably needs to be resolved in the C source code to be properly handled, rather than via Lisp ...

Comment: I figured it out. I need to use `outline-view-change-hook`. I now just need to ensure that this behavior is consistent among the different `outline` folding functions.

Answer (score 1):

### First attempt. Doesn't work, disregard. See below:

I just ran into the same issue and, inspired by @Aquaactress's attempt, added a simple advice to `org-flag-region`:

```
(defun org-flag-region-hide-last (from to flag spec)
  "Unfontify last char of hidden region when folding, fontify it
when showing.

This avoids the bleeding of `org-block-end-line' when block or
parent heading is folded."
  (unless (= (point-max) to)
      (save-excursion
        (if flag
            (font-lock-unfontify-region to (1+ to))
          (font-lock-fontify-region to (1+ to))))))

(advice-add 'org-flag-region :after #'org-flag-region-hide-last)
```

It seems to work well!

(Edit: no it doesn't. It doesn't work well with `org-separator-lines` and it would leave the last char unfontified in some situations.)

### Second attempt. Seems to work:

The above code is still useful (after some adaptations) to deal with hiding the block itself. But, when cycling the outline, we need to hook into `org-cycle-hook`:

```
(defun org-fix-bleed-end-line-block (from to flag spec)
  "Toggle fontification of last char of block end lines when cycling.

This avoids the bleeding of `org-block-end-line' when block is
folded."
  (when (and (eq spec 'org-hide-block)
             (/= (point-max) to))
    (save-excursion
      (if flag
          (font-lock-unfontify-region to (1+ to))
        (font-lock-flush to (1+ to))))))

(advice-add 'org-flag-region :after #'org-fix-bleed-end-line-block)

(defun org-fix-bleed-end-line-cycle (state)
  "Toggle fontification of last char of block lines when cycling.

This avoids the bleeding of `org-block-end-line' when outline is
folded."
  (save-excursion
    (when org-fontify-whole-block-delimiter-line
      (let ((case-fold-search t)
            beg end)
        (cond ((memq state '(overview contents all))
               (setq beg (point-min)
                     end (point-max)))
              ((memq state '(children folded subtree))
               (setq beg (point)
                 end (org-end-of-subtree t t))))
        (when beg           ; should always be true, but haven't tested enough
          (goto-char beg)
          (while (search-forward "#+end" end t)
            (end-of-line)
            (unless (= (point) (point-max))
              (if (org-invisible-p (1- (point)))
                  (font-lock-unfontify-region (point) (1+ (point)))
                (font-lock-flush (point) (1+ (point)))))))))))

(add-hook 'org-cycle-hook #'org-fix-bleed-end-line-cycle)
```

If this doesn't work, try to remove the check for `org-fontify-whole-block-delimiter-line`. That is org-mode's own mechanism for dealing with whole line fontification; maybe some themes define their own methods for achieving whole line fontification, I don't know.

#### Last (?) issue

There is still ONE issue I couldn't resolve... When `org-startup-folded` is `t` or `contents`, the lines still bleed when the file first opens up. You can manually cycle the visibility and they'll behave again, but I could not figure out how to do that automatically at startup.

I tried creating a hook:

```
(defun org-fix-bleed-startup ()
  (when (memq org-startup-folded '(t content))
    (org-fix-bleed-end-line-cycle 'all)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-fix-bleed-startup)
;; also tried:
(remove-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'org-fix-bleed-startup)
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I guess some other functions run after org is loaded which also change the visibility of some parts of the buffer? I don't know.

Please test this and let me know if it works!

Comment: It did not work for me. I evaluated this code and tried out the spacemacs theme but I still see the bleeding. Which theme did you try it on? And what org version?

Comment: Really? Strange... The theme is my own. The face is set with something like `(set-face-attribute 'org-block-end-line nil :foreground "gray90" :background "gray40" :overline t :underline t)`. (That's not **really** the face I use, but I decided to turn lots of features on to see if any bleeding would show up. It doesn't, everything seems to work.) Org version is 9.3.7, built from source. I actually updated it just now to test this. Don't use spacemacs, sorry.

Comment: OHHH, wait a minute. Just noticed that in your screenshot `org-cycle-separator-lines` is set to 1. I tried it and, with that setting, the bleeding DOES show up. I didn't see it because I normally use 0 separator lines... Let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: Yesh. Sorry to spam the comment section, but I just want to say that this is way more finicky and involved than I thought. My original solution didn't really work, even with separator-lines set to 0... When global-cycling after locally hiding a subtree the last char of the end line would still be left unfontified. What a mess; please disregard, and I will keep trying, because this problem annoys me a lot, too.

Comment: Just to be clear, when I say I "try" one of your solutions I mean that I
evaluate your code an enable a theme I know has bleeding, such as the
spacemacs-theme or the built-in leuven-theme.

Trying your latest solution I still encounter bleeding. In fact, with the leuven
theme in particular all visible headlines bleed. I am using org version 9.4. Ah, but the reason for this might be that I use evil-folds instead of org cycle. I'll investigate into this and report back.

Comment: Ah, I don't use Evil or evil-fold. Since it's hooking into org-cycle and org-flag-region, my code probably doesn't even run on your setup. Maybe you can adapt it to work with evil-fold. I made a gif using leuven to show how it looks here: https://i.imgur.com/F80TVYE.gif

Comment: It's ok. I that's a configuration on my end I'd need to resolve. As long as it works for org cycle I'll accept this answer. Just give me a day or so to test it.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer you were looking for, but the simplest way might be to change the `org-block-end-line` variable face to that of the default background, thus ensuring that there's nothing to leak in the first place. Also, end_src line generally seems useless in that all the code-block arguments belong in the begin_line, or better yet an entirely separate #+header:.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I had noticed this when I used themes (like `avk-daylight`) whose background was the same as the src block line. Actually, the line bleeding bothered me so much that I tend to mostly use such themes.

Comment: Like I said, no need to bother with themes, all it takes is addind the '(org-block-end-line ((t (:background "#")))) to the (custom-set-faces) inside the dot file, where # is your background hex.

Comment: You say `no need to bother with themes` but that I need to specify the specific background hex. If I did this what would happen if I changed themes using load-theme? Would I need to change the background hex? If this is the case, this would involve the current theme. This being said, I'm sure there is away to programatically update this value via an advice to `load-theme`. However, even still, I do not feel comfortable accepting such an answer because it introduces a visible side-effect: namely changing the face of `#+end_src` lines.

Comment: If you're asking whether a given theme takes priorty over manually set properties, the answer is it doesn't. Once you explicitly define a face setting it gets rendered above the the load-theme properties.